# What is $\int_0^1 f'(x)e^{f(x)}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Don't be fooled by this innocuous question and answer $e^{f(1)}-e^{f(0)}$! Allow me to trouble you with details.

Suppose $f$ is as smooth as you want, on $\mathbb (0,1)$, so $f'(x)$ exists and is smooth on $\mathbb (0,1)$. But define $f$ to be $-\infty$ outside $[0,1]$ so that $e^{f(x)}=0$ outside $[0,1]$. $f(0),f(1)$ are real numbers though.

I want to know, what is the value of $\int_\mathbb R f'(x)e^{f(x)}dx$? Should it still be $e^{f(1)}-e^{f(0)}$? Or should it be $0$? Think of $e^f$ as basically the truncation of a perfectly nice function to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Why would you care what happens outside the interval of integration? As long as $$f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) \quad \text{ and } \quad f(1) = \lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x),$$ you should be ok to get the difference of exponents.

Comment: It is $\lim_{x\to 1-} e^{f(x)}-\lim_{x \to 0+} e^{f(x)}$ as long as these limits exist. The value of the integral does not depend on what happens outside $[0,1]$.

Comment: Okay, but couldn't I have defined this integral as $\int_m^n f'(x)e^{f(x)}dx$ where $m\to1+$ and $n\to 0-$?

Comment: You need to get a handle on $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. No assumption about what goes on in $(0,1)$ will give you that. After all, we can redefine $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ without affecting either the smoothness in $(0,1)$ or the value of the integral. Limits (from the inside) are needed as gt6989b explained.

Comment: So you are saying that the answer is $\exp(\lim_{x\to 1-}f(x))-\exp(\lim_{x\to0+} f(x))$?

Comment: Exactly @gt6989b. the intgral from 0 to 1 represents a the area under the curve $$f'(x)e^{f(x)}$$ from 0 to 1. since both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are well defined within the given limits, the integral will also be as simple as what you have given above.

Comment: And all of what you are saying is perfectly true even if I am interested in evaluating $\int_{\mathbb R}f'(xf(x)dx$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f$ is only defined at $(0,1)$, then you have an improper integral. So $$\begin{align}\int_0^1 f'(x){\rm e}^{f(x)}\,{\rm d}x &= \int_0^c f'(x){\rm e}^{f(x)}\,{\rm d}x + \int_c^1 f'(x){\rm e}^{f(x)}\,{\rm d}x \\ &= \lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_a^c f'(x){\rm e}^{f(x)}\,{\rm d}x + \lim_{b \to 1^-} \int_c^b f'(x){\rm e}^{f(x)}\,{\rm d}x \\ &= \lim_{a \to 0^+} ({\rm e}^{f(c)} - {\rm e}^{f(a)}) + \lim_{b \to 1^-} ({\rm e}^{f(b)} - {\rm e}^{f(c)}) \\ &= {\rm e}^{f(c)} - \left(\lim_{a \to 0^+} {\rm e}^{f(a)}\right) + \left(\lim_{b \to 1^{-}}{\rm e}^{f(b)}\right) - {\rm e}^{f(c)} \\ &= \left(\lim_{b \to 1^{-}}{\rm e}^{f(b)}\right)  - \left(\lim_{a \to 0^+} {\rm e}^{f(a)}\right), \end{align}$$where the auxiliary $c$ we used was your favorite number in $(0,1)$. Whether the limits above exist or not (which seems to be your concern), "that's between them and god".